# AnimatePresence causing delay when navigating between routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, transition, framer-motion

When I was using the AnimatePresence to add some transitions I got delays between navigating routes even though there are no animations or transitions in my route.

```
import React from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import ProjectsSection from "../Projects/Projects";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "../Layout/Layout";
import Home from "../Home/Home";
import About from "../About/About";
import Transition from "./Tranisiton"; // Correct the import path
import PaddingHandle from "./PaddingHandle";

const RoutesChangesTransition = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="sync">
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <Transition>
              <Layout key={location.pathname} />
            </Transition>
          }
        >
          <Route
            index
            element={
              <PaddingHandle>
                <motion.div
                  key="home"
                  initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                  animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                  exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                >
                  <Home />
                </motion.div>
              </PaddingHandle>
            }
          />

          <Route
            path="about"
            element={
              <PaddingHandle>
                <motion.div
                  key="about"
                  initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                  animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                  exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                >
                  <About />
                </motion.div>
              </PaddingHandle>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="projects"
            element={
              <PaddingHandle>
                <motion.div
                  key="projects"
                  initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                  animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                  exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                >
                  <ProjectsSection />
                </motion.div>
              </PaddingHandle>
            }
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default RoutesChangesTransition;
```

The Transition Component :

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
const Transition = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {children}
      <motion.div
        className="slide-in"
        initial={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        animate={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        exit={{ scaleY: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0, ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1] }}
      ></motion.div>
       <motion.div
        className="slide-in"
        initial={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        animate={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        exit={{ scaleY: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0, ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1] }}
      ></motion.div>
       <motion.div
        className="slide-in"
        initial={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        animate={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        exit={{ scaleY: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0, ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1] }}
      ></motion.div>
      <motion.div
        className="slide-out"
        initial={{ scaleY: 1 }}
        animate={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        exit={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0, ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1] }}
      ></motion.div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Transition;
```

I tried to remove the AnimatePresence and the application works fine but I don't get the exit transition for sure. I don't know why this happens I mean why AnimatePresence make my application so slow and laggy when navigating between different routes?

Edit: The problem is that I have a heavy component so for a reason when I use AnimatePresence I get the laggy between routes.

Comment: The transitions occupy *some* amount of time to allow the transition to occur. That said, I don't see any significant performance issue with your code in this running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animatepresence-causing-delay-when-navigating-between-routes-s9j9dq). It seems to transition just fine. Can you [edit] to clarify in better detail what exactly the performance issue is you are having/seeing?

Comment: when I was in something like "/about" and navigated to "/projects" it took like 2seconds to render the element. That only appears if I wrap my routes with AnimatePresence. Even if I didn't add any transitions yet

Comment: So you are saying that when you remove all the `AnimatePresence`, `Transition`, and `motion.div` components the UI still is slow? Perhaps there is an issue with the components you are trying to render on each route, or something in the `Layout` component? Could you [edit] to include a [mcve] of *that* code? Could you try also creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Thank you! It now works I realized that I have heavy animation when I removed it, It works fine.